# How can I stop the next screen from briefly displaying at the start of a CCTransitionFadeTR?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I am testing transitions in cocos2d, and am running into a problem.

I have a `MainMenu` screen which contains a button.  The idea is that clicking on the button will trigger a `CCTransitionFadeTR` transition to a `WhackMain` screen where there is a `CCLabelTTF` which displays "Hello World".

But when I press the button and start the transition, the `WhackMain` screen appears at full opacity for a moment before the transition from `MainMenu` to `WhackMain` begins.  The transition appears to be working correctly, apart from `WhackMain` being visible for a moment before the transition begins.

How can I keep this from happening?

Here is my code, if it will help identify the problem:

**MainMenu.m**:

```
#import "MainMenu.h"
#import "WhackMain.h"

@implementation MainMenu

+(CCScene *) scene1 {
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene1 = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
MainMenu *layer1 = [MainMenu node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene1 addChild: layer1];

// return the scene
return scene1;
}


-(id) init {
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
if( (self=[super init])) {

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // Create a label for display purposes
    _label = [[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Last button: None" 
                               dimensions:CGSizeMake(320, 50) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter 
                                 fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:32.0] retain];
    _label.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 
                          winSize.height-(_label.contentSize.height/2));
    [self addChild:_label];

    // Standard method to create a button
    CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage 
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.png" selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.png" 
                                target:self selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)];

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    starMenuItem.position =  ccp( winSize.width /2 , winSize.height/2 );



    CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
    starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu];
}
return self;
}

- (void)starButtonTapped:(id)sender {
  [_label setString:@"Last button: *"];
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFadeTR
                                           transitionWithDuration:2 scene:[WhackMain scene2]]];
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**WhackMenu.m**:

```
#import "WhackMain.h"
#import "MainMenu.h"

@implementation WhackMain

+(CCScene *) scene2 {
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene2 = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
WhackMain *layer2 = [WhackMain node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene2 addChild: layer2];

// return the scene
return scene2;
}

-(id) init {
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
if( (self=[super init])) {

    // create and initialize a Label
    CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];

    // ask director the the window size
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild: label];
}
return self;
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc {
[super dealloc];
 }


@end
```

Comment: Dear downvoters.. please leave at least a comment about your reasoning.

Comment: The question is too localized.

Comment: @PeterK Did you try other transitions (other than `CCTransitionFadeTR`) as well? Do they show the same behavior?

Comment: @Gtoknu I don't think it is. Maybe the OP posted unnecessary amounts of code, but the problem might be something that could be of interest for several cocos2d users.

Comment: The question isn't too localised -- it's just worded in a way that's referring to the outcome of the specific problem that PeterK's seeing, instead of to a generic problem that someone else may well also be having.  A minor rewrite making the question about transitions instead of being about "Hello World" would probably help it a lot.

Comment: @TrevorPowell You're right, though, I will just remove my downvote when the question get edited.

Comment: I am sorry if i did something wrong here and yes, i did try other transitions.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, @PeterK.  I've done a little trimming and rephrasing of the question to make it more generic and direct, and hopefully get it a little more attention.  Please feel free to re-edit if I've accidentally misunderstood or distorted your question with my edits!  I can't provide an answer, since I don't know cocos2d.  But hopefully someone will know and be able to see a mistake in your code or something that'll get you back on track.  :)

Comment: @PeterK And when using other transitions, the same problem will occur? What version of cocos2d are you using?

Comment: May i ask how i check the Cocos2d version, can't find where?

Comment: I had this exact issue and it turned out I have some actions that were starting in the new scene and it was trampling the transition. I actually fixed it by adding those objects to a CCNode and adjusting the timings a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried to recreate your problem in one my projects but it doesn't appear for my case.

There are 2 things you can do here.
1. Install new cocos2d framework,
2. If 1st one doesn't work you can schedule a timer that initializes all your nodes in the given scene after 1 sec like this

```
[self schedule:@selector(somefunction:) interval:1.0f];
```

Which is also not a bad choice as when changing the scene the memory usage is at peak and in this way you will reduce the risk of crashing the app due to low memory warnings.

Mostly people use a loading screen which contains nothing more than a label but if you are have problems in transition than i would say go for the second option even if 1st one works.